# WORDPRESS - Plugin Analytics360

Tags: wordpress, plugins, analytics

I have a problem when I try to link my Google Analytics to a website which is on WordPress. (The plugin I use is Analytics360.)

The trouble is that I get to give good access to the site but this one appears right after me:

> ***Hmm. Went something wrong with your Google authentication! The error messages was: 403: Forbidden. If you're having trouble getting
>   up and running, you might try one of the Following resources***

Do you have a solution? Or if someone has already fallen on this problem? :-)

Comment: I forgot this message : Could not fetch visit data: GDatainvalidParameteridsInvalid value 'ga:'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:[0-9]+'

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a plugin for Google analytics, just edit the templates header.php file or use an advanced plugin such as yoast: http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Comment: Yes, but I want to show the analytics in the wp. This plugin, don't show me results